# How do I retrieve parameters from an AngularJS GET HTTP request inside php?

Tags: php, json, angularjs, get

On the Angular side, I'm trying to do a GET http request like the following:

```
$scope.getQuestion = function() {
    //$http.post($scope.url, { src : $scope.question});

    var request = $http({
        method: "get",
        url: $scope.url,
        params:  'index =1',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    });

    /* Check whether the HTTP Request is Successfull or not. */
    request.success(function (data) {
        console.log("GET literally worked");

        $scope.loginMessage = data;//angular.fromJson(data);
        //console.log($scope.testArray["question2"]);
```

But am not sure how to retrieve params (index = 1) from it in php. I tried to do it as JSON but it didn't seem to work?

PHP side:

```
<?php


$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$src = json_decode($data);
//var_dump($_POST);
//$src     = $_POST['src'];
//@$toOut = $src->question;
//file_put_contents("output", $toOut);

/*$arr = array (
    0 => "does this work?",
    "question2" => "i mean i guess?"

    );
$jsonString = json_encode($arr);

echo $jsonString;*/

$numArr = $src -> params;
echo $numArr -> index;
?>
```

So I'm confused on how the params are being read since we aren't passing it to php as $data?

Answer (score 1):

Use an **object** as param instead of a string:

```
params:  {index:1},
```

then in your.php

```
print_r($_GET['index']);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$_GET['index']
```

`params` works the same as url after `?`  when `Method` is `GET`

Comment: I tried to do this and it said that index was undefined